# How to setup rollup for css modules in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup, react-css-modules

I managed to import css modules in my Typescript React Class using [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-plugin-css-modules) from npm.

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "build",
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/*"
  ]
}
```

I also added the following module file in my src/ folder:

*modules.d.ts*

```js
declare module '*.module.css' {
    const classes: { [key: string]: string };
    export default classes;
}
```

It suppressed all warnings and I was able to test my code fine. I have a component which imports a css module located in the same folder:

```
- src
  - components
    - Text.tsx
    - Text.module.css
```

And so my component contains the following import line:

```js
import css from './Text.module.css';
```

I now want to transpile my code to commonjs to use it as a React module in other codes. Here is my rollup config:

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "rollup -c && tsc",
  "test": "jest"
}
```

*rollup.config.js*

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import pkg from './package.json';
import {terser} from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

export default [
    // CommonJS
    {
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
        input: './src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: pkg.main,
                format: 'cjs'
            }
        ],
        external: [
            ...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})
        ],
        plugins: [
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**'
            }),
            typescript({
                typescript: require('typescript')
            }),
            postcss({
                plugins: [autoprefixer()],
                sourceMap: true,
                extract: true,
                minimize: true
            }),
            terser() // minifies generated bundles
        ]
    }
];
```

I am able to run `yarn build` without any errors, however when I look at the built code, the css module file is no longer located next to the Text.js file. Below is a screenshot of the folders generated by build:

[image: build folder tree]

All the css has been moved to the lib folder, and in the generated Text.js file:

[image: Cannot resolve file error]

Is their a way to either preserve the files structure, or to transpile in a way the import points to the correct css file ?

I saw some workarounds with webpack.config.js (running `eject` script), however I'm not quite easy with it (since it adds a lot of files and dependencies to the project, and I'm not sure how to handle everything well).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it ! I found about a preserveModules flag for the rollup config file from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208475/is-there-any-way-to-preserve-directory-structure-of-bundles-when-using-rollup-wi) (with a little fix from [this another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996340/rollup-exceptions-to-preservemodules)). Just edited my rollup.config.js to this:

*rollup.config.js*

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import pkg from './package.json';
import {terser} from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

export default [
    // CommonJS
    {
        preserveModules: true,
        input: './src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                dir: './build',
                format: 'cjs'
            }
        ],
        external: [
            ...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})
        ],
        plugins: [
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**'
            }),
            typescript({
                typescript: require('typescript')
            }),
            postcss({
                plugins: [autoprefixer()],
                sourceMap: true,
                extract: true,
                minimize: true
            }),
            terser() // minifies generated bundles
        ]
    }
];
```

Now it works perfectly fine !

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Exactly what I'm wrestling with myself. I see you've defined your modules def to work only with css. Is there a way to also include scss?

Comment: @Maniaque I haven't worked with scss yet so I'm not sure, but it seems a plugin has been implemented for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-scss

Not sure how similar it is to the postcss plugin I use though, I found some information in this post if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252283/compile-sass-files-with-rollup

Comment: @KawaLo Can you please share screenshot of your build directory with this rollup config. It will help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @MuzamilAbbas Since the post was quite a while ago, I don't think I have the project files anymore. I have also not used rollup recently, so I don't have similar examples available :/