# Compile Sass files with Rollup

Tags: javascript, css, sass, rollupjs

Given is the following simple project structure.

```
.
├── build
│   ├── css
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
│       └── main.min.js
├── package.json
├── rollup.config.js
└── src
    ├── scripts
    │   └── main.js
    └── styles
        └── main.scss
```

`src/scripts/main.js` content is `import "styles/main.scss";`

rollup.config.js

```js
import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss";

export default {
  input: "./src/scripts/main.js",
  output: {
    file: "./build/js/main.min.js",
    format: "esm",
  },
  plugins: [
    scss({
      include: ["/**/*.css", "/**/*.scss", "/**/*.sass"],
      output: "css/style.css",
      failOnError: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Running `rollup -c` with this config results in this output without creating `css/style.css`.

```
> rollup -c
./src/scripts/main.js → ./build/js/main.min.js...
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
styles/main.scss (imported by src/scripts/main.js)
created ./build/js/main.min.js in 7ms
```

What am I missing? How can I use "sass" instead of "node-sass" in the config [per this issue](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-scss/issues/39)?

After running `npm install rollup --global --verbose` and `npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-scss --verbose` the package.json looks like this.

edit 2021-08-06 by John [Compile Sass files with Rollup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252283/compile-sass-files-with-rollup/64253091?noredirect=1#comment121281601_64253091)

```js
npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-scss@3 sass
```

```js
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "build/js/main.min.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^2.28.2",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c"
  }
}
```

Comment: your question was my answer:) thanks

Answer (score 8):

The import of `main.scss` in `src/scripts/main.js` was not quite right.

It has to be `import "../styles/main.scss";` instead of `import "./styles/main.scss";`

With the following `rollup.config.js` the compiled CSS file is saved to `./build/css/style.css`.

```js
import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss";

export default {
  input: "./src/scripts/main.js",
  output: {
    file: "./build/js/main.min.js",
    format: "esm",
  },
  plugins: [
    scss({
      output: "./build/css/style.css",
      failOnError: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

To use "sass" instead of "node-sass" installing "sass" with `npm install --save-dev sass --verbose` and adding it to the config like so works.

```js
import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss";

export default {
  input: "./src/scripts/main.js",
  output: {
    file: "./build/js/main.min.js",
    format: "esm",
  },
  plugins: [
    scss({
      output: "./build/css/style.css",
      failOnError: true,
      runtime: require("sass"),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: This helped a lot.  The one thing that was missing for me was making sure I had the latest version from https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-scss: npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-scss@3 sass